# Populating a dropdownlist according to another dropdownlist in side jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I am having a `jquery accordion` in my asp.net project.
Inside the 1st tab I have 2 `drodownlists`.

1. First one for the ward No.
2. and the other for BHTNo.

Those two are binded with the data in the `database`.
When I select a ward from first dropdownlist I need to load the BHTNo s relavent to that ward, to the second dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use asp.net toolkit feature like CascadingDropDown, it might be resolved your problem
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx